# Regex to find the words in the text which have four consonants in a row?

Tags: regex, computation-theory

I learn regex in Vim and want to find and trying to solve vowel and consonant problems. What is regex for such words?

Answer (score 1):

For 4 consonants in a row, you may try this regex

```regex
(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){4}
```

- `[a-z]` matches an English letter
- `(?![aeiou])[a-z]` matches an English letter, but excludes `a`, `e`, `i`, `o` and `u`
- `(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){4}` for a letter like above, must be 4 in a row

You may see the match result [here](https://regex101.com/r/yNGbIr/1/)

---

If you want to match the whole word other than just those 4 consonants, you may try

```regex
\b(?=[a-z]*(?:(?![aeiou])[a-z]){4})[a-z]*\b
```

See the result [here](https://regex101.com/r/fTgQp9/1/)

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest spelling out the consonants, rather than having all the letters and going through regex hoops to exclude the vowels.

```
[b-df-hj-np-tv-z]{4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
(?i)\b[a-z]*[b-z&&[^eiou]]{4}[a-z]*\b
```